# Make points more linear

Tags: mesh, workflow

I'm beginner on Blender and I don't find how make points more linear like that red line (We can see points up and down the line) :

[image: Wanted result]

Goal is not to make a beautiful render, but a beautiful 3D print.

I know I can set them at the good place one by one but there is a function to help to do that?
I've try the "Smooth" tool (Cube 2x2x2 icon) but the result isn't very good

3D View :

[image]

Comment: Is that surface flat? or are the vertices capturing a curvature? Could you show us?

Comment: The surface isn't flat, see my update please ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option could be to go to sculpting mode and use Flatten [image: icon] tool.

[image]

A little silly to not suggest the smooth [image: icon] tool first:

[image]

Comment: Prety cool :). I don't use sculpting tools, so I had no idea this exists.

Comment: One of the many perks of using a multi-purpose software :)

Comment: Both of these brushes will flatten the shape and change it drastically not preserving the original curvature. The only option is to use Surface Smooth Brush (a smooth brush with *deformation* set to *Surface* under tool settings)